# How to debug websockets with Qtwebkit

Tags: javascript, qt, sockets, websocket, qtwebkit

Is it possible to debug websockets in a application that was made using Qtwebkit?

I've activated the Qtwebkit debugger, but I can't find some tab like the one included in Chrome inspector that's call "network" and filter it by websockets...

Despite this, if not possible with debugger, will be great to know at least techniques on how to debug websockets.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know about qtwebkit specifically. But [Wireshark](http://www.wireshark.org)  should be able to display the websocket traffic from any program on your machine. (If it's over HTTPS, things are [more complicated](http://wiki.wireshark.org/SSL).)

Comment: I tried to used Fiddler but I didn't get any result. I'll look at Wireshark. Thanks @andrewffff!